# jquery icheck current element context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icheck

```
$('.questions input').iCheck({
     checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
     radioClass: 'iradio_line-blue',
     insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>'
});
```

Using this approach does not fit to my needs:

```
$('.questions input').each(function () {

    var self = $(this),
    label = self.next(),
    label_text = label.text();

    label.remove();
    self.iCheck({
         checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
         transferClasses: true,
         radioClass: 'iradio_line-blue',
         insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
    });

});
```

How do I retrive the current context ? I'd like to display the text which is between label tags.
My html looks like

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="question">
         <input type="checkbox" name="iCheck">
         <label>Question answer text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $('.question input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).next('label').html());

});
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/EyGBq/1/)

Comment: Thanks, seems that works fine but I need for each question... right now I'm getting the text and it saves to all check-boxes.

Comment: wait i will also help you in it

Comment: Ok, but seems that I'm back to the example that I have showed in my question (2nd block of code). If I use that then the iCheck pluging doesn't wraps the 'label' element properly

Comment: what problem it will be produced?

Comment: @dreamweiver: you just change the way of event call other same as my code.

Comment: Yes, i changed your code only, as i felt that your logic was generic, it was supposed to extract the label content of the checked element :)

Comment: @Subhash: That the 'label' element is not next to the div, its wrapped inside the div. Check [this link](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) and you'll see the flat and line skins. I want to combine them both. Or write a jQuery generic code for that.